# Open new Chrome tab

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Good day.
Can you please tell if Selenium VBA is possible by opening the Chrome browser to create a new tab, perform some actions in it, close new tab and then return to the first tab and continue working in it?

I open the browser with this code:

```vb
Public drv As New WebDriver

Public Sub browser_open()
Set drv= New WebDriver 'ChromeDriver
drv.Start "chrome", "https://google.com"
drv.Get "/"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
'Ensure latest applicable driver e.g. ChromeDriver.exe in Selenium folder
'VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to selenium type library
Public Sub DownloadFile()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        .ExecuteScript "window.open('https://www.google.com/','_blank');"
        .SwitchToNextWindow
        'do something with new window
        Debug.Print .Window.Title
        .ExecuteScript "window.close();"
        .SwitchToPreviousWindow
        Debug.Print .Window.Title
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```